# to_char produces different outputs depending on where the procedure is called

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, toad

We're using a stored procedure provided by a remote system. For testing purposes, I call this procedure from my development machine. Now the problem is if I call the procedure from **Toad**, everything is OK. But when I call it using **SQL Developer** an error happens.

I debugged and debugged and found out this: In the procedure, an expire date is generated and passed to a web service (don't ask me why).

Here are the lines responsible for generating the date:

```
vt_User.EXPDATE := TO_DATE('01.01.2025', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
vs_Value := to_char(vt_User.EXPDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZR');
```

vs_Value, when called from **Toad** is generated like:

```
2025-01-01T00:00:00+02:00
```

But if I call from **SQL Developer**, it's like:

```
2025-01-01T00:00:00EUROPE/ATHENS
```

Everything except these lines are exactly the same. I tried many different approach, trying to set NLS_LANG, altering the session etc but to no result.

I need to solve this because the same thing happens when I call the procedure from **Java** code also and that's the main issue.

I connect to the remote database using **TNS** for Toad and SQL Developer, **thin driver** for the Java code.

Comment: What is the type of vt_User.EXPDATE ? are you sure it's a date and not a timestamp ?

Comment: it's of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`

Comment: And what do get when you do: select sessiontimezone, dbtimezone from dual;

Comment: try ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE=dbtimezone;
or change the datatype to be TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE

Comment: Great! `ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE=dbtimezone;` has worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: @A.B.Cade Can you explain what was the problem and your solution as an answer?

Comment: Happy to be of some help, @SelimOber did you try also to change the datatype to be TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE ? if so, what were the results ?

Comment: I can't because It's a remote database which I have no control over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle DB you basically have a TIME_ZONE definition for the DB, but you can change it for a session.
In this case the DB time_zone is set in the Absolute offset from UTC  format which is what you want.
Probably the SQL Developer opened the session in Time zone region name format, as could be seen with:

```
select sessiontimezone, dbtimezone from dual;
```

So, altering the session to be as dbtimezone may help.

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE=dbtimezone;
```

Answer (score 0):

have another solution using tzh and tzm:

```
select to_char(current_timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:sstzh:tzm') from dual
```